# php blog won't show first 2 database rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my own simple blog. I got it working so far only 1 very irritating bug remaining.
If I have 4 rows of data in my databse the first 2 (with the lowest ID) won't show up. 
So if I add a new 3rd row only the first row will pop-up my screen and it will take 2 new posts before the 3rd row will show up.
If I turn around the sequence of ID's it does work if I have 2 useless posts in my database.
But ofcourse I want the higher id's to show on top.

Here is the code for putting the database info on the screen:

```
<?php
require('config.inc.php');
require('template.inc.php');
require('functions.inc.php');
include_once('insert.php');

$query="SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );

mysql_close();

htmlOpenen('ServerSideBlog');
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
echo'
<span class="post">
    <h1>'.$db_field['title'].'</h1>
    <h2>'.$db_field['date'].'</h2>
    <p>'.$db_field['contents'].'</p>
    <h3>Hoogachtend, Sincerely, Aufrichtig, sinceramente,</h3>
    <h4>'.$db_field['author'].'</h4>
';
}
htmlSluiten();
?>
```

And here the code for adding the posts in the database:

```
<?php
$db_host = "db.jxxxxx.com";
$db_username = "md2xxxx230";
$db_pass = "J9xxxx58";
$db_name = "md2xxxxx230";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to      mysql");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");

if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "new"){

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $contents=$_POST['contents'];
    $author=$_POST['author'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $date = strftime("%b %d, %y", strtotime($date));

    $sqlcreate = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (date, title, contents, author)
            VALUES(now(),'$title','$contents','$author')");
}

?>
```

I can't find any solution for the problem... Hope I can get some awnsers here :)

Comment: Why are you calling 'mysql_fetch_assoc' three times?

Comment: Dont forget to close the span tag

Comment: Oh - and move away from the deprecated API.

Answer (score 3):

why did you put this before while loop ?

```
$db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );

mysql_close();
```

and secondly you have close the mysql connection before -

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

Comment: This fetches two rows (one by one), discards the second one and closes the database connection. It's the obvious error.

Comment: Otherwise the while loop didn't recognize $result as an array or something so I wasn't able to loop all my database results on the screen.. I've almost no PHP knowledge so if it's terribly wrong please let me know! haha

Comment: Ah ok, but is there a solution?

Comment: what is the result are you getting now?

Comment: @Jos: `$result=mysql_query($query);` defines `$result` so it shouldn't complain about that at the while loop.

Comment: If I could I would vote you all up as much as possible :D Hours of slamming my head to a wall solved in 10minutes :D

Answer (score 1):

You call `mysql_fetch_assoc` in three places. Two times before you enter your `while` loop. Those two times returns the first two rows. So when you enter your `while` loop you start from row #3. Since the code to display the posts are inside the `while`loop it will, obviously, not show the first two posts.

Remove the rows

```
$db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
```

and

```
mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
```

and move

```
mysql_close();
```

to after your `while` loop and it will most likely do what you want.

**Sidenote:**

The way data is added to the database is extreamly unsecure.
The row

```
 $sqlcreate = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (date, title, contents, author)
            VALUES(now(),'$title','$contents','$author')");
```

along with no filtering of the inserted data show that it's highly vulnerable for injection attacks. Both arbitrary SQL code and Javascript could be executed.

*Some information for you:*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: If I could I would vote you all up as much as possible :D Hours of slamming my head to a wall solved in 10minutes :D

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer by clicking the *V* by the answer.